How to turn off collision impulse box2D LibGDX
I have an enemy and a bullet objects, when bullet hits an enemy it disappears but is also cause some impulse to an emeny model. This impulse is small but noticeable.
I tried to set enemy velocity to zero but an offset still appears.
"3" is a bullet index.
public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse contactImpulse) {

    Fixture A = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture B = contact.getFixtureB();

    if (A.getUserData().equals(3)) {   
        deleteList.add(A.getBody());
        B.getBody().setLinearVelocity(0,0);
    }
    if (B.getUserData().equals(3)) {   
        deleteList.add(B.getBody());
        A.getBody().setLinearVelocity(0,0);
    }
}

`


One way of solving this is to use a ContactFilter instead of overriding the postSolve method.
A ContactFilter lets you inspect the Fixtures involved in a collision and you can decide to cancel the collision completely while still have an opportunity to register to hit and add the bullet to your deleteList.
The World class has a method called setContactFilter that allows you to set an implementation of ContactFilter, for example:
    world.setContactFilter(new ContactFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldCollide(Fixture a, Fixture b) {
            if (isContactFilteringEnabled) {
                if ((int) a.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_TARGET && (int) b.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_BULLET) {
                    expiredBodies.add(b.getBody());
                    return false;
                }

                if ((int) a.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_BULLET && (int) b.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_TARGET) {
                    expiredBodies.add(a.getBody());
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

But returning false the collision is filtered out and Box2D ignores it.
In the example below the player is the circle and the target is the square, initially the filtering is disabled, when the second target appears the filtering is enabled (notice that the player can still collide with the target as only the bullet collision is filtered out):

Full source code for the example above:
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

public class SandboxGame extends Game {

    public static final int TYPE_PLAYER = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_TARGET = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_BULLET = 3;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;

    private Body player;
    private Body target;

    private Vector2 toTarget = new Vector2();
    private Vector2 bulletSpawnLocation = new Vector2();

    private Array<Body> expiredBodies = new Array<>();

    private boolean isContactFilteringEnabled = false;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        var viewportWorldHeight = 16.0f;
        var aspectRatio = (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        var viewportWorldWidth = viewportWorldHeight * aspectRatio;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(viewportWorldWidth, viewportWorldHeight);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);

        world = new World(Vector2.Zero, false);
        world.setContactFilter(new ContactFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldCollide(Fixture a, Fixture b) {
                if (isContactFilteringEnabled) {
                    if ((int) a.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_TARGET && (int) b.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_BULLET) {
                        expiredBodies.add(b.getBody());
                        return false;
                    }

                    if ((int) a.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_BULLET && (int) b.getBody().getUserData() == TYPE_TARGET) {
                        expiredBodies.add(a.getBody());
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        player = makePlayer(Vector2.Zero);
        target = makeTarget(new Vector2(4, 4));
    }


    public Body makePlayer(Vector2 position) {
        var bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        var body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setTransform(position.x, position.y, 0);
        body.setUserData(TYPE_PLAYER);
        var fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        var shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(0.5f);
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        shape.dispose();
        return body;
    }

    public Body makeBullet(Vector2 position) {
        var bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        var body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setTransform(position.x, position.y, 0);
        body.setUserData(TYPE_BULLET);
        var fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        var shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(0.1f);
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.01f;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        shape.dispose();
        return body;
    }

    public Body makeTarget(Vector2 position) {
        var bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        var body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setTransform(position.x, position.y, 0);
        body.setUserData(TYPE_TARGET);
        var fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        var shape = new com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(0.5f, 0.5f);
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        shape.dispose();
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        var playerImpulse = new Vector2();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) playerImpulse.y += 1;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) playerImpulse.y -= 1;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) playerImpulse.x -= 1;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) playerImpulse.x += 1;

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
            toTarget.set(target.getWorldCenter()).sub(player.getWorldCenter()).nor();
            bulletSpawnLocation.set(player.getWorldCenter()).add(toTarget);
            var bullet = makeBullet(bulletSpawnLocation);
            bullet.applyLinearImpulse(toTarget.scl(0.05f), bullet.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)) {
            world.destroyBody(target);
            isContactFilteringEnabled = true;
            target = makeTarget(new Vector2(-4, -4));
        }

        for(var expiredBody : expiredBodies)
            world.destroyBody(expiredBody);

        expiredBodies.clear();

        player.applyLinearImpulse(playerImpulse.scl(0.01f), player.getWorldCenter(), true);
        ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK);
        camera.update();
        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 8, 4);
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }
}

